# How do I create this one colour painted matte effect onto any object in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, texture

I have seen this effect created in a few places and want to know how i can apply this effect to any object in photoshop. Here are a few example of posters ive found where it has been executed well.

[image: here is an example of it on black]

[image: here is an example of it applied to household objects]

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this in Photoshop:
Put the objects you want the effect on onto a separate layer. Create a "Hue and Saturation" adjustment layer and check "colorize" then apply the color. (If you want to edit the areas you want the effect, paint on the layer mask). To get the matte effect, add a "Brightness contrast" adjustment layer and link it to the adjustment layer below and reduce the contrast.

The other way would be to use a brush with the "color" mode. Pretty much the same thing as above, but you could apply it to just parts of the image without having to mask it.